# Disposing UserManager and UserStore outside of AccountController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Is this good enough? Or do i have to dispose `UserStore` as well? If i do have to any suggestions would be welcome. I'm new to ASP.NET Identity.

```
using (var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext)))
    {

    }
}
```

This would be better i guess:

```
using (var applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    using (var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(applicationDbContext))
    {
        using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm glad that i asked this question, although i may have already answered my initial question. Thanks Glenn Ferrie, will check out the ASP.NET dependency injection.

Comment: You should use the ASP.NET dependency injection and do not maintain the  lifecycle of these instances yourself.  Are you using OWIN?

Comment: I'm using OWIN. Will check out the ASP.NET dependency injection. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Anyways... Would the code in my answer be "good"/"secure" enough?

Comment: if you are using VS 2013 or VS 2015 RC and you "File > New Project" and create and ASP.NET web application -- you will find the code here: `.\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` -- good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a few code snippets from a new ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6) created with VS 2015 RC.  First the `Startup` class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
// rest of implementation ommitted for brevity.
```

then here is how you access it in a Controller class:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    // NOTE: ASP.NET will use this contructor and inject the instances
    // of SignInManager and UserManager from the OWIN container
    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager )
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }
    // there are implementations for the public properties
    // 'UserManager' and 'SignInManager' in the boiler plate code
    //  not shown here
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Would this work if i'm not inside a controller? Places where context.Get() doesn't exist/is not accessible?